# ansible lineinfile regex multiline

Tags: regex, apache, ansible

I'm trying to edit apache.conf using Ansible. Here's part of my conf:

```
# Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
# not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
# The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
# the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
# your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
# access here, or in any related virtual host.
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
#       Require all granted
#</Directory>
```

I want to change this block

```
<Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

into

```
<Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

set AllowOverride from None to All. I'm using this ansible task

```
- name: change htaccess support
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
    regexp: '\s<Directory /var/www/>\n\sOptions Indexes FollowSymLinks\n\sAllowOverride'
    line: "AllowOverride All"
  tags:
    - test
```

However, AllowOverride All always added to the end of file. What's the correct regex pattern to do this jobs. I don't use ansible template cuz I only change one line.

Comment: you're changing more than one line, and by not using `template` you can't be sure of file correctness/contents.

Comment: decide to use copy module. thanks.

Answer (score 9):

I managed to do exactly this by slightly improving @mattyoung-redhatmatt's answer. As it turns out, the `replace` module handles multi line regular expressions and backreferences just fine:

```
- name: AllowOverride all
  replace:
    dest=/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
    regexp='(<[dD]irectory /var/www/>[^<]*)AllowOverride None'
    replace='\1AllowOverride All'
    backup=yes
  sudo: yes
  notify:
    - restart apache
```

Comment: replace's multi line understanding will break if you use .* instead of [^<]* in your expression. The '.*' is a very common expression and here replace will not work. The reason: by default '.' matches any characters except a new line: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL. But yes best answer so far :)

Answer (score 2):

I tried and I tried to use blockinfile for this and I did not want to use a full template. I ended up using ansible's replace module and practicing a little regex on regex.com:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Update apache2.conf
      replace: dest=/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
        regexp='<Directory /var/www/>\n\tOptions Indexes FollowSymLinks\n\tAllowOverride None'
        replace='<Directory /var/www/>\n\tOptions Indexes FollowSymLinks\n\tAllowOverride All'
        backup=yes
      notify:
        - restart apache2
  handlers:
    - name: restart apache2
      service: name=apache2 state=restarted
```

Comment: I'm trying to match a multiline entry to use for the `insertafter` parameter, which I suppose ist just a regexp with a different function ? I'm actually trying to us blockinfile to add a DNS zone in the /etc/named.conf which should come after the whole `Zone "." IN {};` block. I'm trying now with .*, but if that doesn't capture the newlines, I will try your approach. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ansible's [lineinfile](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/lineinfile_module.html) module does precisely just that, it deals with single lines in files and has [no support for multiple lines](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/557).

This leaves you with a couple of options to tackle this problem instead.

As with most tricky things around lineinfile you might be best replacing this with a [template](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/template_module.html) instead.

Alternatively you could try using the [blockinfile](https://github.com/yaegashi/ansible-role-blockinfile) role to first remove (`state=absent`) the following block:

```
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
```

after `<Directory /var/www/>` and then inserting (`state=present`) the following block:

```
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
```

after `<Directory /var/www/>`.

Comment: thank you. but I decide to use copy module to recplace file.