# How to insert a line not immediately after a match using Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to insert a line after 2 lines of match.

```
- name : Update compute node under  ipsec group
  lineinfile:
    backup: yes
    state: present
    path: /root/multinode
    insertafter: '\[ipsec:children\]'
    line: "hostname"
```

file:

```
[ipsec:children]
control
```

Result:

```
[ipsec:children]
hostname
control
```

Desired Result:

```
[ipsec:children]
control
hostname
```

Basically I want to insert 1 line after the match, not in the immediate next line.

Please let me know how to do this.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33094075/ansible-lineinfile-regex-multiline

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to use [blockinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/blockinfile_module.html) (see example below), or [template](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/template_module.html). Module [lineinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lineinfile_module.html) works best with non-structured data.

> This is primarily useful when you want to change a single line in a file only. ... check blockinfile if you want to insert/update/remove a block of lines in a file. For other cases, see the copy or template modules.

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    ipsec_children_conf:
      - "control"
      - "hostname"
  tasks:
    - blockinfile:
        path : /root/multinode
        create: yes
        block: |
          [ipsec:children]
          {% for conf_item in ipsec_children_conf %}
          {{ conf_item }}
          {% endfor %}


> cat /root/multinode 
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
[ipsec:children]
control
hostname
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
```